# Password Type Default Unmask

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Android TextInputLayout with password type. I see a mask/unmask icon. How can I set the text to unmasked by default?

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:theme="@style/EditTextMaterialTheme">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // When you define your edittext in oncreate method, that time put below line    
     youreditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should be like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:theme="@style/EditTextMaterialTheme">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And in your java class write these lines

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout2);
        textInputLayout.passwordVisibilityToggleRequested(true);
```

Comment: I don't think this answer the question.
But if it is documentation, is here: https://medium.com/@moyinoluwa/password-visibility-toggle-android-support-library-revision-24-2-0-98b422087e5a

Comment: I have walked through this article but if we will not write java code lines it will not work until